# Is this variable a JavaScript array or JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Can you please take a look at the following code and let me know if the `data` is a JavaScript array or JSON?

```
var data = [
  [ 20 , 20 ],
  [ 20 , 30 ],
  [ 50 , 35 ],
  [ 40 , 20 ]
];
```

If it is an array, can you please let me know what kind of array it is?

Comment: It's a two-dimensional array of numbers.

Comment: Its an array or arrays of numbers. Basically a multidimensional array 2D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is a 2-dimensional array.

JSON is a format for representing data as a string, for storing in files or transmitting over the network. It uses a subset of the syntax for Javascript literals. So the JSON representation of that object would be the string:

```
"[[20,20],[20,30],[50,35],[40,20]]"
```

Comment: @user3649067 don't forget to accept the answer when you can (in 5 minutes)